# cPanel login / passwords

Tags: cpanel, cpanel-xmlapi, cpanel-uapi

I try to understand. We have 1 cPanel, so domains.
I have users and passwords at:

```
/home/{USERNAME}/etc/{HOSTNAME}/passwd
/home/{USERNAME}/etc/{HOSTNAME}/shadow
```

What's login for cPanel ? {USERNAME}@{HOSTNAME} ? or what ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For login cPanel Using {USERNAME}

Comment: and what's at /home/{USERNAME}/etc/{HOSTNAME}/shadow ?

Comment: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcshadow-file/ Read This...Hope You get idea.